# Differentiate 1-m-wide unvegetated creeks from vegetated surrounding using WorldView-3 or 4 images

Tags: naip, worldview-3

I see that both WorldView-3 and 4 have a panchromatic band with resolution 0.31 m. Then they have spectral resolution of 1.24 m (4 bands in WorldView3 and 8 bands in Worldview 4). I need to detect with a machine learning (Deep Learning) algorithm creeks that have a width of 1 m or little more. The 0.31 m resolution would be enough if it was multispectral, but since it is panchromatic, the way they achieve 0.31 m resolution is via [panchromatic sharpening](https://eos.com/make-an-analysis/panchromatic/#:%7E:text=A%20panchromatic%20band%20can%20be,a%20high-resolution%20color%20image.). Therefore, I feel like indexes to identify vegetation such as [NDVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_difference_vegetation_index) will not be recovered at the 0.31 m scale, but they will be only be meaningful at 1.24 scale. Do you think I could be able to differentiate  1-m-wide unvegetated creeks from vegetated surrounding? If not, am I maybe better to resort to [NAIP](https://www.fsa.usda.gov/Internet/FSA_File/naip_info_sheet_2013.pdf), that is 1 m quad-band resolution (and 0.5 m for some other areas since 2011)?

Comment: Pretty open-ended question, but short answer is using veg indices on pansharpened multispec data is still going to work fine for differentiating veg v. non-veg. My question is why do you need to use deep learning? That seems like a lot of work for something a simpler algorithm could achieve, like SVM or Random Forests. You could almost just use a threshold on NDVI. I would look at using an object-based approach though. NAIP imagery might work better in this case if the veg is still obviously green.

Comment: Thank you, with working fine are you saying that I can differentiate veg non veg at a 0.31 m resolution? Deep learning is just an idea, I agree with you it might be overkill, my question is general and independent on the algorithm

Comment: Whether you can differentiate or not depends on the characteristics of the veg you are trying to map - size, colour, health and how it stands out against the non-veg areas. But there is no issue using the pansharpened data to derive NDVI, etc.